# How to Sum the number of records that have a particular lookup field value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database that includes a table (tblQA) with a lookup field. That Lookup field (CPT) contains 4 values Pass, NonPass, FYI, and Both. (In that order so the id value of NonPass is 2) I have a continuous form that is based on a query that gives me the records for a particular user for a date date range. What I want to do is be able to sum the Total number of records that come back as NonPass.

I've tried Sum([CPT].NonPass) but that didnt work and my search of stackoverflow only came back with a user that didnt give enough info to answer the question. I also tried to include a text field for each record in the continuous form with some VBA on button to convert any value of 2 to a 1 in the text box and then I was going to sum the text boxes, but that didnt work either, I think because each text box was the same name so the button just made all of the text boxes the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sum` function (and other aggregate functions) in the footer of a continuous form can calculate a sum (or other aggregate) of expressions that are based on fields of the record source of the form, but it can't be used to calculate a "Sum of Textboxes". You want to count the records having `[CPT] = 2`, so use a formula like this:

```
=Sum(Iif([CPT] = 2, 1, 0))
```

This expression does not reference any control on your form, just a field of the underlying table/query (`CPT`).

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew there was something basic I wasn't understanding. Thank you for the answer!